# How to destroy a custom view

Tags: android

So I have a custom view I'm implementing, and would like to know how to destroy it when it is clicked. I've tried using onClickListeners, implemented both in and outside of the activity, I've tried calling invalidate() to no avail. At this point I'm stuck with an empty onTouchEvent method and no clue of how to destroy the view when it is clicked.

P.S. By destroy I mean make it disappear from the UI thread.

Answer (score 11):

You can remove the `view` from its `parent Layout`  to make it `disappear/destroy` like this

```
 parentLayout.removeView(customView);
```

Or , You can `hide` the `View` to disappear and show it back later if required

```
 customView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: What's the difference between View.INVISIBLE and View.GONE? With View.GONE it will be destroyed?

Comment: `View.INVISIBLE` hides the `View`, but it's still present within the hierarchy. With`View.GONE`, the `View` is taken off of the hierarchy in addition to being invisible. Neither methods 'destroy' the `View`, but they do *hide* it.

Comment: `View.INVISIBLE` takes space in the parent view, where `View.GONE` does not.